# Adding a camera to a model in Gazebo? (Beginner)

Tags: ros, gazebo, camera, sensor, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am very new to using things like Gazebo and ROS. I was wondering about how one might take a model from Gazebo (like turtlebot or quadrotor) and attach a camera to it, and see the feed?

My guess is that I have to go into the code of the model files and add camera code? But I am unfamiliar with the code or how it works. And how would I get the feed? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Can someone please guide me through this process? I have Gazebo5, and I am running Ubuntu.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210695/adding-a-camera-to-a-model-in-gazebo?-(beginner)/) by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more a Gazebo question than a ROS question (so I should refer you to the [gazebosim.org](http://gazebosim.org) site), but what you ask is described in one of the [Gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials), namely the [Connect to ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins&cat=connect_ros) one.

If you've never done any of this (urdf, sdf, ROS, Gazebo, etc), I really recommend doing the ROS or (actually: *and*) Gazebo tutorials first (or find a book about it), and only then move on to more advanced things. Everything will seem really convoluted and incomprehensible otherwise (at least, that is what many students/people tell me is their experience).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on 2015-06-06**:
Okay never mind, I figured it out. This wasn't nearly as complicated as I thought haha, the .sdf files have a very intuitive format, and I think as a programmer it wasn't too hard to work it out.

I will try giving myself a crash course using the tutorials you have provided. Thank you!

**Comment by [ssaniljainn](https://answers.ros.org/users/70072/ssaniljainn/) on 2021-02-25**:
Hey, did u figure this out? I am in a similar situation. The problem is that the iris model that I have does not have the iris.xacro file. Just 2 files  - model.sdf and model.config. I am using ROS Kinetic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend to go through this : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera
My solution is to just add the following in your iris.sdf :

```
<link name='cam_link'>
  <pose frame=''>-0.118317 0.002195 0.004205 -0 -0 -3.12703</pose>
  <inertial>
    <mass>0.1</mass>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>1</ixx>
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>1</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>1</izz>
    </inertia>
    <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
  </inertial>
  <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  <sensor name='camera1' type='camera'>
    <camera name="head">
      <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <width>800</width>
        <height>800</height>
        <format>R8G8B8</format>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>0.02</near>
        <far>300</far>
      </clip>
    </camera>
    <always_on>1</always_on>
    <update_rate>30</update_rate>
    <visualize>1</visualize>
    <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
    <cameraName>iris/camera</cameraName>
    <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
    <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
    <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
    <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
    <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
    <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
    <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
    <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
    <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
  </plugin>
  </sensor>
```

---

Originally posted by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) with karma: 178 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2